# In which site asking for code is on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

Is there any site on Stack exchange network that allows to ask for code (or reference to code) in a particular programming language for a given problem?

Comment: It's going to depend on the specifics of what you're asking for as to what site, if any, that might be appropriate on.

Comment: None, that I'm aware of.

Comment: I am asking for general code asking platform like, 

ex : 'python code for subset sum problem', 'Julia code for generating permutations', 'C code for K nearest neighbor classifier' etc.,

Comment: @Confused The place to ask those questions is [here](http://google.com)

Comment: @Servy But, most of the times, the codes over Google may not be as per requirements and obeying restrictions needed.

Comment: @Confused Then you try to adapt them to suit your needs.  If you can't, you might have created a specific problem which you can clearly explain indicating what you're trying to do, what you're doing, how it fails to solve your problem, what research you've done on existing solutions to that problem, and how they fail to work for you.  After having done that, you might have a question that's on topic on a site here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites are designed to create a collection of knowledge by helping users with very specific problem statements so other can solve those problems on their own.

Unfortunately, questions soliciting users to *build something for me* are not allowed on these sites. And posts sending users elsewhere for solutions are not considered an 'answer' in the context of a Stack Exchange site because posts are expected to contain complete solutions.

There are rare exceptions like "Puzzling" and "Code Review" where folks engage in exercises of solving problems and improving *working* code. But Stack Exchange is not meant solicit code or other work and should be 'flagged' if it occurs.